# Predicting multivariant linear model in R

Tags: r, lm, predict, poly

I have a question regarding a prediction for linear model with two variants (multivariant). I am trying to use a model I trained to predict new data. I have this code that trains z in terms of x and y. The data is around 60,000 rows:

```
fit <- lm(z ~ poly(x, y, degree = 4), data = data)
```

Then I want to predict just one row by doing the following

```
x <- -20
y <-  20
data2 <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))
prediction <- predict(fit,data2)
```

The r throughs this error:

```
Error in Z[, 2] <- x - alpha[1L] : replacement has length zero
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try `predict(fit, newdata = data2)`

Comment: also in your example you are missing a `)` in `data2 <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))` but even better just do this `data.frame(x,y)`

Comment: It did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code using the reproducible input shown in the Note at the end runs without any error messages.

```
fit <- lm(z ~ poly(cbind(x, y), degree = 4), data = data)

data2 <- data.frame(x = -20, y = 20))
predict(fit, data2)
##        1 
## 436884.4
```

### Note

```
set.seed(123)

n <- 25
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n), z = rnorm(n))
```

Comment: This works perfect! May I ask why I need to do the cbind in the training step?

Comment: If you type `poly` at the R command line it will dislay the code and you can review it and see how it works.